# Single custom marker google maps API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, onclick

I have been working with Google Maps & Places API and have successfully got it working using react hooks to allow the user to drop markers, onClick info window, auto-complete place search and Geolocation.

However, what I need is that onClick it will only add a single marker which will change location every time the user clicks a new coord. Not add multiple markers on every click as it currently does.

Code below:

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);


  const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
    setMarkers((current) => [
      ...current,
      {
        lat: event.latLng.lat(),
        lng: event.latLng.lng(),
        time: new Date(),
      },
    ]);
  }, []);

...

return (

 <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={13}
        center={center}
        onClick={onMapClick}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
      >
        {markers.map((marker) => (
          <Marker
            key={marker.time.toISOString()}
            position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
            icon={{
              url: "/crane-pin.svg",
              scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(40, 40),
              origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 15),
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelected(marker);
            }}
          />
        ))}

...

  </GoogleMap>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your use case, you need to have access to the `marker object` and use the [`setPosition` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setPosition) to change the position of the marker to the clicked coordinates in the map.

Are you using any google maps react library? Here is a [sample reactjs code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/samp-simple-map-with-marker-change-position-onmapclick-qcexcx?file=App.js) that implements this without using any react libraries. Code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Map from "./Map";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Map
          id="myMap"
          options={{
            center: { lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446 },
            zoom: 12,
          }}
          onMapLoad={(map) => {
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: { lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446 },
              map: map,
            });

            //Changing Marker position for clicked coordinate
            map.addListener("click", (event) => {
              marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```